# I need to get sum of income for each user in January. Which of these 3 MySQL queries is more efficient?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to get the sum of income for each user in January 2016 which is represented by the payments and commissions, not deposits. Table of records looks something like this (millions of records):

```
USERNAME  AMOUNT   TRANSACTION        DATE
user_1       1     Deposit #1       2015-12-12 23:19:00
user_2       2     Payment #2       2015-12-23 13:45:00
user_2       7     Commission #3    2016-01-04 23:45:00
user_1       1     Payment #4       2016-01-09 20:25:00
user_3       2     Payment #5       2016-01-17 02:42:00
user_1       3     Commission #6    2016-01-23 18:30:00
user_3       2     Deposit #5       2016-01-29 09:58:00
...         ...    ...              ...
```

My 3 queries are:

```
SELECT username, SUM( amount ) AS monthly_amount
FROM balance_history        
WHERE MONTH( date ) = 1     
AND YEAR( date ) = 2016     
AND (transaction LIKE 'Payment%' OR transaction LIKE 'Commission%')
GROUP BY username
```

Or

```
SELECT username, SUM( amount ) AS monthly_amount
FROM balance_history        
WHERE '2015-12-31 23:59:59' < date AND date < '2016-02-01 00:00:00'     
AND (transaction LIKE 'Payment%' OR transaction LIKE 'Commission%')
GROUP BY username
```

Or

```
SELECT username, amount, transaction        
FROM balance_history        
WHERE '2015-12-31 23:59:59' < date and date < '2016-02-01 00:00:00'     

AND THEN DOING THE SORTING, SUM, AND OTHER CALCS WITH PHP
```

I would go with the 3rd one, but I would appreciate other inputs.

Also, Is there any tool to measure the "efficiency" of a query?

Thank you all and happy new year!

Comment: Do you have any indexes on this table ?

you can have an idea of the efficiency of your query by using EXPLAIN : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: it does have a column 'id'....

Comment: considering your query and the large amount of data you have in your table, you should definitely consider creating indexes on columns "date" and "transaction" ... in that case, the second query should be the more efficient ...

Comment: Doing a date comparison date > '2016-...' is faster that using MONTH() and YEAR()?

Comment: if you have an index on date, then yes ...

Comment: ok I will give a shot thank!

Comment: see my answer to your question for more information ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no index on `date` column, then the 1st and the 2nd query should take approximately the same amount of time (as they both scan the full table)

I would not go for the third one : if you have a lot of data, you can possibly reach the PHP memory limit, furthermore MySQL have good algorithms to do the calculations you want to do, why not using them ? :-)

however I would suggest you create an index on the column `date`

```
ALTER TABLE `balance_history` 
ADD INDEX `idx_date` (`DATE` ASC);
```

**important note :  depending on your production server performance and load this could block your table for several minutes - test it on your development environment first !**

once the index is created, the second query will be the most efficient one :

```
SELECT username, SUM( amount ) AS monthly_amount
FROM balance_history        
WHERE '2015-12-31 23:59:59' < date AND date < '2016-02-01 00:00:00'     
AND (transaction LIKE 'Payment%' OR transaction LIKE 'Commission%')
GROUP BY username
```

if you use MONTH( date ) or YEAR( date ) in a WHERE clause the index on date is useless : you will be scanning the full table ...